# One time/set up jobs on gitlab ci?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up a pipeline that compiles and builds new docker images, and then deploys those images to testing kubernetes cluster.

I'm using a shell runner.

I need to setup my `kubectl` client to point to the testing kubernetes cluster. (ie. setting the cluster and context).

As I understand it - I should only need to run this once. Is there a way to get this to run once, as defined in the `.gitlab-ci.yaml`? Or should I just repeat the set up steps everytime in `before_script`?

Comment: It widely depend on how you want to configure kubectl, I'd go with env vars and keep it in a before script, this would be idempotent and allow a move to containers later also

Comment: @dwjohnston what did you try? Please add the .gitlab-ci.yaml.

Comment: Why is defining it in the `before_script` not sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with the same issue. Some people recommended using the Gitlab group "secrets" and using `before_script`. Since I knew I was also going to deploy and would need other tools on my runner like "helm", I made my own docker container. I still keep my config for my clusters in a base64 encoded group secret but I set it like this in the dockerfile.

```
ENV kube_config=$kube_config
RUN echo -n ${kube_config} | base64 -d > ~/.kube/config
```

Now just set an environment variable for your gitlab runner to point to your new image.

```
KUBERNETES_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/MY_USERNAME/MY_REPO_NAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

Don't forget to test your new container!

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/gitlab_runner:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/gitlab_runner:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install docker.io -y
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

Build Image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg kube_config=${kube_config} -t ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE}
  except:
    - master

Test Kubectl:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE}
    - docker run --rm ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE} kubectl get deployments -n kube-system
  except:
    - master

Test Helm:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE}
    - docker run --rm ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE} helm ls
  except:
    - master

Test Docker:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE}
    - docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ${CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE} docker images
  except:
    - master

release-image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
    - master
```

Edit: Missed this part.. **I'm using a shell runner.**

So post of what I said is probably not relevant. How ever I do think there is some advantages to building and deploying with a gitlab runner directly on a cluster.